# Complex conjugate of angular momentum operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, angular-momentum, complex-numbers

I am trying to derive relation 5.7.5 in " **The Quantum Theory Of Fields** " by *Steven Weinberg* :

$$-J^{(j)^*}_{\sigma,\sigma'} = (-1)^{\sigma-\sigma'} J^{(j)}_{-\sigma,-\sigma'}\tag{5.7.5}$$

Does somebody know how to derive this formula?

Comment: For those of us who don't have the book, can you provide the definition of this operator?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to PSE. You will need to give context to your question and definitions enough for anyone who does not have the book as a reference.